# Adding a new sub-element to multi-dimensional array based on a condition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I can achieve this easily enough with loops, but it seems messy and I wondered if there's something that could be done with array_map or similar?

Given the following array:

```
[1]=>
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(25)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(100)
  ["total"]=>
  int(125)
}
[2]=>
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(11)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(38)
  ["total"]=>
  int(49)
}
[3]=>
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(20)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(100)
  ["total"]=>
  int(120)
}
```

How would you go about flagging the index with the lowest total?

e.g. to change it to:

```
[1]=>
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(25)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(100)
  ["total"]=>
  int(125)
}
[2]=>
array(4) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(11)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(38)
  ["total"]=>
  int(49)
  ["lowest"]=>
  bool(true)
}
[3]=>
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(20)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(100)
  ["total"]=>
  int(120)
}
```

(adding `"lowest" => false` to the other indexes is unnecessary but acceptable)

Many thanks, I can't get my head around it.  My brain seems to be failing me, it's been a long day.

Comment: loops will be involved no matter what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `array_column()` we can retrieve subarray. Then using `min()` find the lowest value and find corresponding key using `array_search()`:

```
$total = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, 'total'));
$minKey = array_search(min($total), $total);
$array[$minKey]['lowest'] = true;
```

To preserve original keys here's also combination of `array_keys()` and `array_combine()`

Comment: Except `array_column()` will return a 0 based array.  So the search will return index 1 but in the original array the minimum is at index 2.

Comment: Thanks!  To my eye it's not super obvious code so I'll probably stick with a loop as at least that's easy to read/understand, but I learnt something here :)